# Does anyone here know what (if number % 2 == 1) does?

Tags: python

Does anyone here know what (if number % 2 == 1) does? I saw it in a for loop program but I can not find the answer can any one help?

```
    numbers = [ 951, 402, 984, 651, 360, 69, 408, 319, 601, 485, 980,
    507, 725, 547,544, 615,
    83, 165, 141, 501, 263, 617, 865, 575, 219, 390, 984, 592, 236, 105, 942, 941,
    386, 462, 47, 418, 907, 344, 236, 375, 823, 566, 597, 978, 328, 615, 953, 345,
    399, 162, 758, 219, 918, 237, 412, 566, 826, 248, 866, 950, 626, 949, 687, 217,
    815, 67, 104, 58, 512, 24, 892, 894, 767, 553, 81, 379, 843, 831, 445, 742, 717,
    958, 609, 842, 451, 688, 753, 854, 685, 93, 857, 440, 380, 126, 721, 328, 753, 470,
    743, 527
    ]
if number % 2 == 1:
    continue
print number
```

Did I mention it was python?

Comment: @RC.: complete with the very same numbers. Good find!

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh! I didn't see the numbers! :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters probably some homework...

Comment: @RC. Sorry I checked the questions for about 5 minutes did not see that. Probably just scrolled pasted it.

Comment: @ChrisWesseling No it is not it is from http://www.learnpython.org/en/Loops so I can learn Python.

Comment: I see. I'm not against homework. Learning Python is fun and useful. No matter if you do it in school, from a book or on a site. You recognized SO's value as a learning aid. Good. You just have to use its search function a bit more extensive. And keep having fun.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`%` operator](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) calculates the modulus (integer remainder); `number % 2` gives you the remainder of `number` divided by 2:

> The `%` (modulo) operator yields the remainder from the division of the first argument by the second.

It basically tests if the number is odd (which gives you a remainder of `1`), skipping to the next iteration of the loop if it is.

Answer (score 2):

Checks that the number is odd.

Comment: That's an accurate and very succinct answer, but perhaps a little more explanation would have helped.

Comment: I know. That's why the other answer got 4 upvotes and the tick. :)

Answer (score 0):

The % function takes the remainder of a number after it is divided by another number.
ex:
  print 5%2
  output = 1

5 is divided by 2. Then there is a remainder of 1 afterwards.

Therefore the (if number%2 == 1) function tests to see if the number is odd. If it returns true then your program continues and print the number. If the number is not odd the program ends.

Comment: Your answer is correct. But what does it add to existing answers? And did you read the comments? This question itself is already a duplicate.

Comment: @ChrisWesseling While you're correct, it'd be worthwhile pointing this out to users who have been around for a while and might have themselves after this scores of times.

Comment: sorry, that was my first answer ever, and it was actually a question that i knew how to answer so i just went ahead and did it.

Comment: @devnull Sorry if I came across rudely. I was trying to be helpful. But I disagree that its not worthwhile pointing out to newbies. But a welcome from my part would be in place... Welcome at SO user3475916 ;-) We're not all coldhearted gits like myself here. You'll find most will be gentler, like devnull.